# How to disable the default JQM page in a SPA?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have a single page JQM application - all JQM "pages" are in one document:

```
    <div>
        @RenderPage("Views/login.cshtml")
        @RenderPage("Views/page1.cshtml")
        @RenderPage("Views/page2.cshtml")
    </div>
```

How can i disable displaying a JQM page by default, which currently happens to be the login.cshtml, so i can manually invoke the transition method to erase the login page from the history, after the user has logged in ? Eq this is what i want to invoke manually on initial document load:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#login-page', { reverse: false, changeHash: true });
```

Alternatively, is it possible to set the "reverse" attribute to false without a `changePage` call?

Comment: Your application logic is wrong... You shouldn't be rendering the login page at all if the user is logged in. And you technically shouldn't be rendering the other pages if they're not logged in!

Comment: @ahren This is the presentation part of the single page application. They can't access any web service calls without authentication anyway, so i don't see what the issue here is. Also, only one page at a time is rendered to the user from the JQM. The rest of the logic of the application hasn't got anything to do with the problem.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to decide which page is going to be displayed? Login page if use is not logged in or page1 if user is already logged in?

Comment: @Gajotres I currently have control over how the pages are displayed, but i can't seem to find a way to remove the login page from the navigation history - so when a user logs in, or is logged in and gets redirected, they are still able to navigate back to the login page via browser's back button. This would be solved with $.mobile.changePage (demonstrated in post), but in my case, where the whole application lies on one document, the login page gets displayed first automatically, which doesn't allow me to navigate to it via "$.mobile.changePage".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want I can give you a client side solution.

Basically you an use my older example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/3PhKZ/ to prevent page transition if some condition is not fulfilled. And at that point you can forward that user at any other page with changePage function.

This solution will work in any case because it will trigger during every page transition and if next page is in your case login page it will look at conditions and do whatever you want. You can allow that transition, prevent it altogether or simply redirect to an another page:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforechange', function(e, data){  
    var to = data.toPage,
        from = data.options.fromPage;

    if (typeof to  === 'string') {
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(to);
        to = u.hash || '#' + u.pathname.substring(1);
        if (from) from = '#' + from.attr('id');

        if (from === '#index' && to === '#second') {
            alert('Can not transition from #index to #second!');
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            // remove active status on a button, if transition was triggered with a button
            $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active ui-focus ui-btn');;
        }  
    }
});
```

Comment: I have yet had a chance to test this, but doesn't this stop the navigation completely? For example: User navigates from stackoverflow.com -> login.cshtml -> page1.cshtml, *presses back button" but is unable to return to stackoverflow.com and is stuck in page1.cshtml.

Comment: As I told you in my answer this will prevent pagechange but will not skip this page. This is just a solution what you can do.